# About the validity of the dilute gas approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-monopoles, confinement

In the compact QED (cQED) in $(2 + 1)$ dimensions confinement /deconfinement property is described in terms of boundness of monopole-antimonopole pairs (Berezinskii-Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transition).

I am reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04924.

Here the author works in the **dilute monopole gas approximation**, where

- Sum  is carried only with magnetic charges $q_a = \pm 1$
- Monopoles are non-overlapping

In the partition function the gauge field $A$ (its perturbative) part and monopoles (represented by density $\rho(x)$ ) are decoupled:
$$
Z = \int \mathcal{D} A \sum_{\text{mon}} e^{-S[A, \rho]} = Z_{ph} \cdot Z_{\text{mon}}
$$
Here
$$
\sum_{\text{mon}} = \sum_{N = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N!} \prod_{a = 1}^{N} \left(\sum_{q_a = \pm 1} \int \bar{\zeta} d^3 x_a \right)
$$
Here the integration is carried over all possible positions of monopoles, and the factor $\frac{1}{N!}$ corresponds to the permutation symmetry. $\bar{\zeta}$ is the fugacity parameter, controlling the density.

The action of the Coulomb as is given by:
$$
S^{\text{mon}} [\rho] = \frac{g_{\text{mon}}^2}{2} \sum_{a \neq b}^{N} q_a q_b G(x_a - x_b) + S_{0}^{\text{mon}}
$$
Where $S_{0}^{\text{mon}}$ is a divergent self-energy term, which is absorbed in renormalization of the fugacity parameter:
$$
\zeta(x) = \bar{\zeta} \exp \left(-\frac{g_{mon}^2}{2} G(0)\right)
 = \bar{\zeta} \exp \left(-\frac{2 \pi^2}{g^2} G(0)\right)
$$
Then there is switch to the finite temperature regime, and the finite part of Green`s function has a an expression, similar to those of massless bosonic gas in 2d:
$$
G_{T}^{2d} = -\frac{T}{2 \pi} \ln T |\vec{\rho}|
$$
Then this Green function is substituted in the expression for the action, and one gets:
$$
S^{\text{mon}} [\rho] = \frac{T g_{\text{mon}}^2}{4 \pi} \sum_{a \neq b}^{N} q_a q_b \ln T |x_a - x_b| 
$$
The rough way to estimate the transition temperature is to multiply the prefactor, formed by the number of states with $e^{-S}$ :
$$
N(r) = \left(\frac{L}{a} \right)^2 \frac{2 \pi r}{a}
$$
Where the first number counts all possible positions of the pair of monopoles, and the second one - the relative orientation. Finally:
$$
Z_{mon} \sim \frac{r}{a} \exp (-S_{M \bar{M}}) = \exp \left(\left(1 - \frac{T g_{\text{mon}}^2}{4 \pi}\right) \ln \frac{r}{a} \right)
$$
The exponential factor from the action, and the entropic factor, accounting all possible configations cancel each other at:
$$
T_c = \frac{g^2}{\pi}
$$
At $T > T_c$ large $r$ are unfavored, and monopoles are bounded, and unbounded at $T < T_c$.

My question:

> Is the dilute gas approximation justifiable in this case? Working with
> finite density seems to be impossible by analytical methods, but can
> be the case that for the dense gas the transition temperature would
> change drastically, or the transition may behave in very different
> way?